# Continuity and limit of union of curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by:

$f(x,0)=1+x^2, \; f(0,y)=1+y^2 \text{ and } f(x,y)=0 \text{ if } x\neq 0 \text{ and } y \neq 0$

a) Is $f$ continuous on $(0,0)$?

b) $\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x }(0,1) \text{ exists? }$ And $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}(1,0)?$

**My attempt:**

This function is the "union" of two parabolas, one is on $x$ plane and the other is on $y$ plane. But I am not sure how to prove whether it is continuous or not. Indeed, the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are $0$ and the function is zero for all the other points such that $x \neq 0$ and $ y \neq 0$, but I don't know if it is sufficient, in this case, and how to argue if so.

For the second question

$\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x }(0,1) =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x,1) - f(0,1)}{x} =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0- (1+1^2)}{x} $
and so there is no partial derivative (same for $y$). Is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

a) Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,0)=1\neq 0 \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$$ it can't be continuous.

b) yes, it's correct.

Comment: For $x \not =0 $ we have $ f(x,x) =0$ and  $f(x,0)=1+x^2.$, Now let  $x \to 0$.